# How to add a custom key-value pair to a grok pattern?

Tags: filter, key-value, grok

How can I add a custom key-value pair to a grok pattern?

For example, I would like to add a key-value pair of `"city": [["New York]]` to the data result, even though it doesn't exist in the log line.

How do I do this? Tyvm, Keith :^)

**Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable Example**

Data:

WARN 10/11/2017 kmiklas

Grok:

%{WORD:logLevel}\s%{DATE:date}\s%{USER:user}

```
{
  "logLevel": [
    [
      "WARN"
    ]
  ],
  "date": [
    [
      "10/11/2017"
    ]
  ],
  "DATE_US": [
    [
      "10/11/2017"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "10",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "11",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2017",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "DATE_EU": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "user": [
    [
      "kmiklas"
    ]
  ],
  "USERNAME": [
    [
      "kmiklas"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that will be a fixed field, so you need to use the `mutate` method, like this:

```
mutate { add_field => { "city" => [["New York"]] } }
```

if you want the new `field` to be only in some logs you need to include `if`

```
if "some_test" in [message]{mutate.....}
```